# Is there any way to force subtitles in a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I uploaded a video in French on YouTube but a non-negligible number of English-speaking people are going to watch it. I uploaded the `.srt` file and everything works fine when I press the "CC" button.

However, I would like to force subtitles when I embed the video on my blog. I read the instructions [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/force-subtitles-embedded-youtube-video/) but they don't work anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: This question and answer were helpful to me except that I don't know that they work for iOS. My iPhone still won't display my videos' captions by default: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38839377/470749

Comment: I would rather like to know how to pass a URL parameter to turn the subtitles on. Embedding with subtitles is documented widely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can.

> If you are the video owner, you can make captions appear by default by
>   adding this tag to your video: **yt:cc=on**. It won't stop people from
>   turning them off by clicking the CC button, but it will default
>   captions to 'on' for most users.
>
> **Embedded videos**
>
> - When you embed a video on another site, you can make it so that
>     captions are always shown on the embedded video. To enable captions on
>     a video you'd like to embed, just add **&cc_load_policy=1** to the video's
>     embed code.
> - You can also choose a caption language for the embedded
>     video. To specify the caption language for the video that you'd like
>     to embed, just add **&hl=fr&cc_lang_pref=fr&cc_load_policy=1** to the
>     video's embed code. Here, **hl** sets the language for the player menu,
>     **cc_lang_pref** sets the language for the captions shown in the video,
>     and **cc_load_policy=1** makes captions on by default. fr represents the
>     ISO 639 language code for French. You can look up 2-letter language
>     codes in the ISO 639-1 standard.

[Source](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140174)

Comment: from next time please don't only post links. Post the possible answer here. So that the question gets better visibility by search engines and people can find answers quickly.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: this yt:cc=on doesnt work with mine

Comment: Not sure if anything's changed, but when linking to videos on YouTube try `cc=1` instead of `cc_load_policy=1`

Comment: Funny how this is came up higher on the search list in Google than the original source.

Comment: I answered a very similar question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127072/150335).