# Force subtitles in video on YouTube, if it's not embedded

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I have uploaded the video on YouTubeand added the subtitles but the users don't realize that they can turn them on. I know there is particular URL parameter for embedded player, but it doesn't work for `youtube.com` itself. I have tried:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWMMgHobF6g&hl=de&cc_lang_pref=de&cc_load_policy=1
```

and it returns the page in German, but does not turn the subtitles on.

How can I force YouTube to use subtitles on `youtube.com` itself?

Comment: For others researching the same: right now, only `&cc_load_policy=1` seems to work, as it turns the CC on, but no language can be set... pity, it's so convenient to share links properly

Answer (score 10):

The only way I found is changing the URI from

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s3aJfRr9gE
```

to this pattern

```
"https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" + VIDEO_ID + "?hl=" LANG_CODE
```

If `hl=` doesn't work (in some cases doesn't seem to work) try `cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=`.

On bash/Linux you can just copy the URI with that structure and then run this command (Spanish code hard-coded) to transform clipboard content (you can make an alias):

```
xclip -selection c -o | echo "$(cat -)?&amp;hl=es-419" | sed "s|youtube.com/watch?v=|youtube-nocookie.com/embed/|1" | xclip -selection c
```

You can list the available subtitles [ISO 639-1 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) with [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html):

```
youtube-dl --list-subs "{video_id or url}"
```

Drawbacks:

- the video will cover the complete screen... which might be good thing to stop procrastinating with related videos :)
- It seems that doesn't work with automatic generated captions.

Comment: This seems to change the UI language, but doesn't show the subtitles.

Comment: But adding &cc_lang_pref=de&cc_load_policy=1 (e.g. https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/TPifNZKb1og?hl=cs&cc_lang_pref=cs&cc_load_policy=1) seems to work!

Comment: The only downside is that this domain generates less trust than a YouTube link. But this seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

This solution effects your videos on the platform aswell as when you embed it.

Go to "Youtube Studio" and click on the video where you want to force subtitles.

Scroll down to tags. Add `yt:cc=on` will force subtitles. Add `cc_lang_pref=en` to select preferred subtitles.
[image]

Make sure that you have published the preferred subtitles as extra language, even if you just want to use the auto-generated ones.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works! So YouTube never actually stopped using `yt:cc=on` ... but they started to require `cc_lang_pref=en` or whatever language you like on top

Comment: This does not seem to override the default settings of English as the UI and subtitle language.

Comment: It seems that it is not working anymore. I also tried including hl=es or even adapting it to the same format than cc=on; that is: yt:cc_lang_pref=es and yt:hl=es, but nothing worked to display the Spanish subtitles as default.

Answer (score 4):

I've found out how to do it.

Add

```
&hl=de&cc_lang_pref=de&cc=1
```

to your video url, and subtitles will be on youtube.com by default. Of course, you need to use your language instead of `de`.

Comment: Not working anymore :(

Comment: that was a dirty hack with limited lifetime :D